# Artificial neural network trained with image

Tags: image, artificial-intelligence, kinect, software-design

I am interested in creating a software which detects an object like a pen using Microsoft Kinect. I recollect 100 positives images an 200 negative images in order to be taken by artificial neural network. My question is: how can I convert these images to be the input of the ANN? I guess that last layer has one neuron because is one output is or not pen and I guess that the input is one too I want to use 3 layer in total. But I don't know if I should convert positive and negative images in matrix or what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I've never personally dealt with using the Kinect for image recognition, but if its possible, you should scale down the image to a fairly reasonable size such as `100x100` so that its is still manageable.

You should also try to convert the image to `grayscale` as this will also help with computational efficiency, time of development, and it's much easier to start of with than RGB.

The input layer will *not* be 1, that's a given. If we're referring to the image that has 100x100 dimensions, the total number of inputs should be `10000`, one for each pixel. Remember, you're trying to breakup the data as fine-grained as you can so the ANN can detect patterns in the data.

The output layer should actually have 2 `neurons`, and for a good reason. Remember, each output neuron is measuring the likelihood that the input belongs to that respective class. By having 2 neurons, each one can represent the positive class (Yes, this is a pen) or the negative class (no, this is not a pen). So, by having 2 neurons, you can get the probabilities that the image will belong to that class, and then you can choose the highest value as your answer.

3 Total layers should be sufficient, you'll probably never need more than that. There are some very good articles for you to determine the amount of layers to have, such as [this one](http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/707)
I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: If I train ANN with cropped images(only contain object that I want to recognize) Should I crop images in order to test ANN?

Comment: You sort of have to, or else it wouldn't work since the input layer should be the size of your image in number of pixels.

Comment: But If I train ANN with images that object that I want to recognize is in the center of images and When I show a images that the object is in the left Can ANN recognize that¡? because I have the problem that I told you ANN only recognize the object if I crop images leaving object that I want to recognize

Comment: It should be able to, but try to maybe find images of pen that are outside of the middle, just to give your ANN more exposure to different data

Comment: It works, my problem was my second class(non pen) I trained my second class using images of apple and it works.Well I have a question about second class, If I want to recognize if image have a pen or not. First class I will use images of pen and second class Can I use images of tables for example I put a pen on table ANN recgonize that image contain a pen but when image contain only a table ANN reocgnie that image do not contain pen